# Select div -class tag using Jsoup with Java

Tags: java, html, class, jsoup

I want to select
`<div class="article_text">some long text </div>` with Jsoup.

```
String url = "computerworld.bg/45781_sofiya_teh_park_tryabva_da_bade_zavarshen_do_kraya_na_2015_g";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new URL(url).openStream(), "ISO-8859-1", url);
Elements elements = document.select("div.article_text");
```

Then I want to iterate over elements and to get theri text.
But the div is not selected. If I only try with div as css selector the correct text information is showing, but there are another not appropriate divs texts, so I have to use the class name.

Where is my wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax) obviously says it is ok.

```
Element masthead = doc.select("div.masthead").first(); // div with class=masthead
```

So, I think `_` is causing the problem. Try with `div[class=article_text]` as selector, and if that doesn't work then `div[class^=article]` (class starts with article), but it could select more than you would want.

**UPDATE**

`div.article_text` works on online Jsoup tester (http://try.jsoup.org/) with url from your code. Maybe the issue is how you are getting the document. [This example](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/load-document-from-url) uses `Jsoup.connect()`

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.computerworld.bg/45781_sofiya_teh_park_tryabva_da_bade_zavarshen_do_kraya_na_2015_g").get();
```

**UPDATE 2**

Turns out this particular url returns different content based on user agent (without user agent set, `article_text` is not present on that div), so just set `userAgent` to, for example, `Mozilla` and it will work.

```
Jsoup.connect("http://www.computerworld.bg/45781_sofiya_teh_park_tryabva_da_bade_zavarshen_do_kraya_na_2015_g").userAgent("Mozilla").get();
```

Comment: Both ways do not work. If I iterate over all elements and print their classes I saw that div elements' class have no name. And I think this cause the problem.

Comment: If I try:
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.computerworld.bg/45781_sofiya_teh_park_tryabva_da_bade_zavarshen_do_kraya_na_2015_g"   ).get();
System.out.println(doc.select("div.article_text").first());
using  <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.1</version>
The result is null again

Comment: Yes, I tried there but locally do not work? And I am confused now.

Comment: @Xelian Finally got it (had to download jsoup to try it :) ). You need to set user agent, because html content depends on it. Check `update 2` in my answer.

Comment: @Xelian Quite expected actually, different browsers / devices / user agents require different page layout. For example, page looks different on desktop browser compared to smartphone browser. One way of customizing it is through different html.